# Swift Syntax Explanation

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Swift programming. When looking at the information about search bar, I saw the following statement. Can anyone explain to me what does it mean as I could not find any related information.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredNFLTeams = unfilteredNFLTeams?.filter { team in
            return team.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    } else {
        filteredNFLTeams = unfilteredNFLTeams
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my questions:

1. 1searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty1 - what is the "," in this statement?
2. `in..return` - how to to use it?

I apologize for any confusion as I don't even know how to ask.

Comment: Read the Swift Language Guide. Seriously. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

A Swift `if`/`guard` statement can check more than one condition at a time before it runs its block of code. You separate its conditions with a comma. In this case, `searchController.searchBar.text` must have a value (which will be assigned to `searchText`), and the text field must not be empty. If either one of these aren't true, the code inside the `if` block will not run. However, this must be combined with `let` syntax in the condition

The `in` is part of the syntax of the closure used here. A closure is a lot like a function, but it can be passed around and assigned to variables and such. You can see more about the syntax of closure syntax [here](http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com)

Comment: You do not use a comma to separate conditions in a general `if` expression. This comma is like a "where" in an `if let` statement.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your details explanation. May i know what is the different between "," and "&&". I tried to put "&&", it came out an error message.

Comment: @GFONG `let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text` doesn't return a Bool (or anything), therefore you can't use `&&` to combine it with another `Bool`. See: [Logical AND (&& ) Operator](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/swifttm-for-programmers/9780134021584/ch04lev2sec16.html)